# JavaScript - Get width of element during css transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, css-animations

I want to display an element's width in javascript. This part is already working, but here is my issue :
When the element's width is animated, during the animation I want to see the real element's width, and not the final element's width.

I'm working with Angular, and what I wanted to do was possible by including JQuery using the function `$(el).width()` but I want to remove JQuery uses.

I already tried (assuming `el` is a HTML element) :

```
el.offsetWidth
el.clientWidth
el.scrollWidth
el.getBoundingClientRect().width
```

Comment: You wrote `getBoundingRect().width` is it a typo or you tried `el.getBoundingClientRect().width` already?

Comment: It was a typo mistake, sorry. I updated the question

Comment: And how did you call the code you are showing? All of these should work: https://jsfiddle.net/mqe9hgb1/ [(and same in case of transition)](https://jsfiddle.net/mqe9hgb1/1)

Comment: You could try to listen to the `animationiteration` event http://wilsonpage.co.uk/animation-iteration-event/

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I faced the same issue, with images who are not loaded yet and had the size of 0. I fixed the problem with using the following code to get the original image size. Be sure you continue your code inside the `onload` function

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {

    // set its dimension to target size
    var width = image.width;
    var height = image.height;
};
image.src = el.img;
```

It is also possible to do this with a base64 string if needed

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {

    // set its dimension to target size
    var width = image.width;
    var height = image.height;
};
image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + img;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but I wasn't talking about an image to load. My issue concern any elements animated with transitions css